# Use case for the form type extension / access from encapsulated JavaScript to generated form IDs

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I read the documentation for the form type extension on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html

> Form type extensions have 2 main use-cases:
> You want to add a generic feature to several types (such as adding a "help" text to every field type);
> You want to add a specific feature to a single type (such as adding a "download" feature to the "file" field type).

I read the chapter but at the end I ask me, how to control which field type get which extension?

In the example the name of the extension must match to the field type which should be extended. So the extension would be applied for every field with the given name.

But how can I write one extension and use it for different field types (with different names)?
Or how can I only use the extension for one specific field?

I don't see any reason to use an extension but rather to extend a field type

**//edit**
What I want to do is to add ajax autocomplete functionality for some form fields (don't use bundles, for better understanding, when coding it myself).
I read the and tried out the model-transformer part with success, but I have problems on other areas.
For example I want to do custom JavaScript and styles for the form fields.

And I know how to customize the form fields (overwriting blocks, themes). But how can I put JavaScript code for specific form fields into the HTML head and get access to the generated HTML ids of the input elements? And also access from the JavaScript to the options which are passed as parameter when building a form like

```
$builder->add('field', 'custom_type', array('opt1' => true, 'opt2' => 'foo'));
```

Comment: Well, this is a good question and the shorter answer I can find comes from the documentation: `Form type extensions can achieve most of what custom field types can do, but instead of being field types of their own, they plug into existing types.`. Do you currently have a case where you don't know which one to choose or is it more a general question?

Comment: In my opinion the described use case in the doc are phrased mistakable. For me, I want to write my own extension for ajax autocomplete.

Comment: For ajax autocomplete, I used a Custom Form Field Type with a data transformer. If you haven't read it, it may help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: @cheesemacfly Yes I know the data transformer, but I have some other issues. Look at my post again, I added my use case

Comment: To access the field id I just check the rendered HTML and copy/paste the id. I don't know if it's good or bad practice but it works...I understand better your situation but can't help...Hope someone will answer, I am really interested to do something like this as well.